# Может ли приложение-клавиатура получать доступ до URL страницы в браузере?

Tags: android, ios

Планирую создание приложений для iOS и Android, одной из составляющих которых будет клавиатура (сам не разработчик, приложение закажу на аутсорс, в данном же случае интересует только теоретическая возможность). 
Суть вопроса - возможно ли, чтобы клавиатура моего приложения считывала адрес страницы в браузере, на которой находится пользователь, и передавала его в приложение, позволит ли OS это делать? Касается вопрос как iOS так и Android.

Comment: Что-то я не уверен в возможности вообще сделать клавиатуру под iOS. В смысле клавиатуру для всех приложений, а не только для своего.

Comment: Почему же? Есть множество приложений с клавиатурами, которые можно использовать в любом приложении - App Store ими под завязку набит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, невозможно. Клавиатуры на iOS крайне ограничены в доступной им информации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
А не подскажете также  за Андроид? Может хоть там возможно?